# How to implement thread mutex with kthread?

Tags: linux-kernel

I know that we can use `pthread_mutex_init` and `pthread_mutex_lock` to implement thread mutual exclusion. But how can I implement it in kernel module with `kthread`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot use the `pthread_mutex_*` functions as these are userspace-only calls. In the kernel use the use the mutexes provided by [linux/mutex.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.1/include/linux/mutex.h):

```
struct mutex my_mutex; /* shared between the threads */

mutex_init(&my_mutex); /* called only ONCE */

/* inside a thread */
mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
/* do the work with the data you're protecting */
mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
```

Comment: The link you offered is quite useful to me, Thank you very much!